# Is the Chai BDD style 'should' async?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, chai

I've been having lots of weird issues with my unit tests (see for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34076345/tests-failing-with-mockgoose-cause-mongoerror-topology-was-destroyed) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34072735/mocha-chai-tests-using-mongoose-occasionally-fail-on-first-run)) and I wanted to rule out this as a possibility. So, here's my potentially silly question:

Does the [`should`](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/) style from Chai block, or is it async? Is it safe to have a `done()` call after some sort of `should` chain, or is the ideal solution callbacks of some sort?

I'm pretty sure this isn't the problem. But it seems like I discover a new problem caused by Node's non-blocking IO (or rather, my lack of experience with it) every day and I wanted to check that I wasn't making a mistake here.

Comment: I've had weird experience with ```.should``` because it needs to attach itself to object you are ```should```-ing. I had better experience with ```expect()```. And sync/async depends on test runner. ```mocha``` is sync. And every assertion with ```expect()``` is sequentially run, and is atomic, so there is no async operation there. Same goes for ```should```.

Comment: Do you want to make that an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had weird experience with `.should` because it needs to attach itself to object you are `should`-ing. I had better experience with `expect()`. And sync/async depends on test runner. `mocha` is sync. And every assertion with `expect()` is sequentially run, and is atomic, so there is no async operation there. Same goes for `should`.

Answer (score 1):

i prefer expect over should because something.should will throw an error if something is undefined. no other reason for my preference.

neither should nor expect make the test async. done is what makes the test async and the done should be called in both the promise resolution and reject block (not just one). you may want to tweak the mocha (i assume mocha) timeout period before done fails. hope this helps.